# How do I get the hover state on one element to change the style of another?

Tags: css, html

I've seen variations of this around the site but I'm running into a hurdle with my own.

I'm trying to adapt this code to work with a UL in a table on top of these two divs.  When you hover over backslide4 first4 slides.

```
div.backslide4:hover div.first4 {
-webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: left ease-out .5s;
left: 360px; }
```

For my UL I've tried the following with no success:

```
ul:hover div.first4 {
-webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: left ease-out .5s;
left: 360px; }
```

You can see an example here [Test Link](http://www.greenheartfoods.com/dev).  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: For a `CSS` hover to work the object that is being effected has to be a child of that element.

Comment: @JoshPowell not entirely true. It can also be a next sibling http://jsfiddle.net/bR3Jp/ Though a previous sibling is not supported.

Comment: Very interesting! I was not aware of this.

Comment: I'm not seeing any hover styles for the ul in the css? Are you sure you added your bit?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: the code looks like it should work, as long as div.first4 is a child of ul...

Comment: Solved. Moved the UL element to child of div.first4 and it worked instantly.  Thanks all!